# The difference between the child and the decendent selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

These appear to do the same things. I've never been sure what the difference is.

```
<style>
    #a > b > i{
        color: blue;
    }
    #b b i{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<div id="a">
<b><i>text</i></b>
</div>
<div id="b">
<b><i>text</i></b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

***There is difference***.

The `>` is a **child** selector which selects only **direct/immediate** elements where as `#a  b  i` will select child elements at any depth inside the specified parent.

For your markup:

```
<div id="a">
<b><i>text</i></b>
</div>
<div id="b">
<b><i>text</i></b>
</div>
```

Both should work but still child selector is more appropriate in that situation. Consider this:

```
<div id="a">
<b><i>text</i></b>
</div>
<div id="b">
<b><i>text</i></b>
<b><i>text<div><span><i>text</i></span>></div></i></b>
</div>
```

In the above case though, the child selector will not be applied on `<i>` inside the span       element in `<div><span><i>text</i></span>></div>`, which is not a direct child of `<b>`element.

**More Info:**

[CSS Child Selectors](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/qt/tipcsschild.htm)

Comment: typo in 3rd word ;) difference

Answer (score 1):

Right from the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/conform.html#doctree)

> **Child**
>       An element A is called the child of element B if and only if B is the parent of A.
>   **Descendant**
>       An element A is called a descendant of an element B, if either (1) A is a child of B, or (2) A is the child of some element C that is a descendant of B.